# How to split a dataframe into two based on data from another dataframe (before and after some action) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split a dataframe with posts using data of date and time of registration into two dataframes, where I will have data of posts before and after registration.

A dataframe with posts:

```
posts = {'Login':['User1', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User3'], 'Posted':['13.12.2018 07:12', '13.05.2019 00:00', '13.05.2019 12:32', '13.06.2019 00:06', '01.07.2019 14:43']}
df_posts = pd.DataFrame(posts)
```

A dataframe with dates of registration:

```
registr_date = {'Login':['User1', 'User2', 'User3'], 'Registered':['14.12.2018 12:07', '17.05.2019 14:01', '20.06.2019 15:00']}
df_registr = pd.DataFrame(registr_date)
```

I changed the format of columns with time and date:

```
df_posts['Posted']= pd.to_datetime(df_posts['Posted'])
df_registr['Date_of_registration']= pd.to_datetime(df_registr['Date_of_registration'])
```

I need to get the following output.
Posts before registration:

```
    Login   Posted_before
0   User1   13.12.2018 07:12
1   User2   13.05.2019 12:32
2   User3   13.06.2019 00:06
```

Posts after registration:

```
    Login   Posted_after
0   User1   13.05.2019 00:00
1   User3   01.07.2019 14:43
```

How I should split the dataframe with posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can convert datetime with proper format and then make a dictionary with key as login and value as registered, and apply this map of Posted date as below.

```
df_posts['Posted']= pd.to_datetime(df_posts['Posted'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
df_registr['Registered']= pd.to_datetime(df_registr['Registered'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

map_user = dict(zip(df_registr['Login'], df_registr['Registered']))

df_posts['pre_register'] = df_posts.apply(lambda x: x['Posted'] < map_user[x['Login']], axis = 1)

pre = df_posts[df_posts['pre_register']]
post = df_posts[~df_posts['pre_register']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.merge:

- Please beware that using `.to_datetime` with out format argument can cause confusion on date and month.

```
df_posts['Posted']= pd.to_datetime(df_posts['Posted'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
df_registr['Date_of_registration']= pd.to_datetime(df_registr['Registered'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

df_merge = pd.merge(df_posts,df_registr, on = 'Login')
df_before = df_merge[['Login','Posted']][df_merge['Date_of_registration'] > df_merge['Posted']]
df_after = df_merge[['Login','Posted']][df_merge['Date_of_registration'] < df_merge['Posted']]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [LaChatonnn mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60274180/12838321), please use the format option when converting to DateTime

I usually prefer using `.map` over `.merge` if possible as it results in better performance

```
# Convert to datetime
df_posts['Posted']= pd.to_datetime(df_posts['Posted'], format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
df_registr['Registered']= pd.to_datetime(df_registr['Registered'], format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

# Set index in register df to allow mapping
df_registr = df_registr.set_index('Login')

# create the split dfs
df_before = df_posts[(df_posts['Posted'] < df_posts['Login'].map(df_registr['Registered']))]
df_after = df_posts[(df_posts['Posted'] > df_posts['Login'].map(df_registr['Registered']))]
```

**Output:**

df_before:

```
    Login   Posted
0   User1   2018-12-13 07:12:00
2   User2   2019-05-13 12:32:00
3   User3   2019-06-13 00:06:00
```

df_after:

```
    Login   Posted
1   User1   2019-05-13 00:00:00
4   User3   2019-07-01 14:43:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 df_posts['Posted'] = pd.to_datetime(df_posts['Posted'], format='%d.%m.%Y 
 %H:%M')

 df_registr['Registered'] = pd.to_datetime(df_registr['Registered'], format='%d.%m.%Y 
 %H:%M')

 df_merge = pd.merge(df_posts, df_registr, on="Login")
 df_before = df_merge.loc[df_merge['Registered'] > df_merge['Posted']]
 df_after = df_merge.loc[df_merge['Registered'] <= df_merge['Posted']]
```